# Voltage monitor when discharging

Tags: batteries, pcb, discharge

I am trying to make a discharge system that use 2R2 resistors and relay to engage the system, until here everything is fine, I can trigger the system and discharge the battery.

[image]

I thought, that I could add a voltage monitor on the BATT trace and monitor the voltage but apparently I messed up something which I cant understand.
If I dont solder the 2R2 resistors ( R1 and R29 ) , I can sense the voltage and detect when it is dropping.

Once I have the 2R2 resistors soldered, I am not able to read it due to the voltage dropping almost to 0 on the reading circuit.

I am using an ATTiny and using the analog input to read the voltage with the following schematic

[image]

Comment: what does that 4.7k and 1M voltage divider network do? 4.7k is almost nothing compared to 1M

Comment: which `AQY21x` part?

Comment: What's the battery you're looking to discharge? If you're sampling continuously, what's the ADC sampling rate? Otherwise, what's the time difference between triggering the relay and sampling the battery value?

Comment: @muyustan the voltage divider is a way to read the voltage with an Arduino

Comment: @Jasen that is just a relay to switch

Comment: @EarthLord I am not looking at high rate sampling, even once a second less often is fine. I am just stuck on this dilemma

Comment: you are not dividing voltage to anything, that's what I say

Comment: which part number...  different AQY21x have different performance, maybe you have the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider also R1 and R29 in your voltage divider.
What you have is a (4.7K + 1M) || (R1 || R29).
If I understand you correctly and R1 and R29 are 2.2Ohm -> you can calculate the equivalent resistance you get.